# Unique relationship attribute for every pair of entities

Tags: relational-theory, unique-constraint

I have entities "Student" and "Course" and they are connected with relationship many-to-many called "Exam". The relationship "Exam" has an atribute "Grade". For this ER model, I have made a relational schema:

```
Student(StudentID, StudentName, DoB)
Course(CourseID, CourseName)
Exam(StudentID, CourseID, Grade)
```

Can someone explain how would you put in a relational schema the fact that a student can't get multiple grades for a single course? For example, we can't have records like `(Student1, Course1, Grade1)` and `(Student1, Course1, Grade2)`.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the forum! See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f5446478b78f86ad166b7f41442047e8) for a schema which  might be applicable to your requirements - if not, let me know and I'll put together one that is. Student_1, Course_1 - Christmas exam and Summer exam? Many/Most colleges allow students to repeat for a variety of reasons so having two grades for the one course mightn't be that unusual - however YMMV...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a relational database every table should have a Primary Key.

A Primary Key can be one column, like StudentId, or it can be a Compound Key, like (StudentID, CourseID), which is exactly what  you should use for Exam.

Then Exam's Primary Key guarantees that "a student can't get multiple grades for a single course", because that would require multiple rows with the same (StudentID, CourseID) values.

Answer (score 1):

You would create a unique constraint on `exam (StudentId, CourseId)` this would usually be achieved with a unique index on that table that covered the two columns.

[Here's a quick demo in MySql](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccdcbe32efe3ddcdcfc788cc42e36481)